# PKI authentication over proxy, python 2.6.6

Tags: ssl, urllib2, python-2.6, http-proxy, pki

I am trying to do PKI based authentication over proxy.
It works well without proxy, but asa I add proxy info it returns 401 error.

```
proxies = {
  'http': "http://10.192.72.155:8080",
  'https': "http://10.192.72.155:8080",
}

def open_url(url, key, cert):


    headers = {"User-Agent": "<custom>", "Accept": "<custom>"}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cert=(cert,key), timeout=300)
    print response.headers, response

open_url("https://api.example.com/product/LatestUpdate", "/usr/bin/dev_certs/test_cert.key", "/usr/bin/dev_certs/test_cert.pem")
```

The above implementation works well, untill I add proxies to the requests.get()

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, cert=(cert,key), timeout=300)
```

which returns following error:

> HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
>   WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=""
>   Server: SomeServer
>   Connection: Keep-Alive 
>   Content-Length: 35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was my proxy setup, it was also decrypting HTTPS traffic, because of which it was not passing the original Certificate.  It worked after I disable HTTPS decryption.